# Basic Shell Script call command from another director with feedback

Tags: macos, shell

i'm trying to create a shell script so that it calls two commands in 2 seperate directories and then shows their feedback, To call the a command i'm guessing it would be something like this ./directory/ ./script.sh

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: And what's not working?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sequentially invoke the commands:

```
/path/to/command1; /path/to/command2
```

If you want to call the second command only if the first one succeeded:

```
/path/to/command1 && /path/to/command2
```

If you want to run them in parallel:

```
/path/to/command1 &
/path/to/command2
```

The output of the commands will be the standard output (most likely the terminal). If you run the two commands in parallel and they produce some output, you might want to redirect it to different files.

Comment: Avoid the mixing of output with GNU Parallel: parallel ::: /path/to/command1 /path/to/command2